# Using bluebird Promises, how can I do a nested each?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I have 2 arrays and I want to do something to each combination of them. For example:

```
var array1, array2;

array1 = [1, 2, 3];

array2 = [4, 5, 5];

async.each(array1, function(val1, cb1) {
  return async.each(array2, function(val2, cb2) {
    return doProcessing(val1, val2, function(err) {
      return cb2(err);
    });
  }, function(err) {
    return cb(err);
  });
}, function(err) {
  return console.log('DONE');
});
```

How can I do this with bluebird Promises?

I am using the `async` module here because `doProcessing` is an async call.

Comment: Updated to JavaScript instead of CoffeeScript

Comment: What version of node/io are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all about `doProcessing` promisify it:

```
process = Promise.promisify(doProcessing);
```

There is no sense in working with callbacks in this case if you already have bluebird included. 
Now it returns a promise and you can easily work with it. As for the other part of the question you need all pairs - you can refactor that to an async nested for loop:

```
return Promise.each(array1, function(val1){
     return Promise.each(array2, function(val2){
          return process(val1, val2);
     });
}).then(function(){
    // all done
});
```

Note that if the arrays contain just numbers do a normal loop rather than promises - each is useful here in case the values are themselves obtained from an async source.

Alternatively - here is a more functional way with Ramda:

```
var all = Promise.all.bind(Promise);
var wait = R.compose(all, R.map(all), R.xprod);
wait(arr1, arr2).map(R.apply(process));
```

Comment: +1 for the Ramda way although I'm not sure how/whether it works. Wouldn't it need to be `all(R.map(all, R.map(R.map(process), R.xprod(arr1,arr2))))`?

Comment: @Bergi the zen of Ramda is that everything is curried by default and data is passed last. What wait does here (simplified a bit) is create a function that first gets the cross product and then maps over the result with `all` effectively waiting for each array. This talk is great at giving intuition for that style of programming http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3svKOdZijA

Comment: Oh, I do have the intuition already, but I say that `all` needs to be executed *after* the `process`?

Comment: @Bergi the values in `[a1, a2]` for a1 from arr1 and a2 from arr2 need to be unwrapped _before_ they are passed to `process` - compose in Ramda is done right to left. Note that the returned result of `wait` is a bluebird promise - calling `.map` on it implicitly calls `.all` (this is unlike `array#map` in which case your comment would have been spot on.

Comment: This is different from the less functional version in that it _first_ creates all the pairs and then executes `process` on them.  It's also to be fair concurrent on all pairs (can be `.each` to be sequential).

Comment: Ah, I see now, it's creating a promise for the promises of the pairs… which didn't found very useful as the arrays contain primitives. And then it uses Bluebirds `.map()` method which does the implicit all… instead of `compose(all, R.map)`

Comment: Yeah, I did not want to assume the arrays contain primitives since I did not do that in the non - ramda version - if they just contain primitives it's just a `R.compose(all, R.apply(process), R.xprod)(arr1, arr2)`

Comment: `R.map(R.apply(process))`, but yes :-)

Comment: Static methods in bluebird don't use `this` so the bind is not necessary